# Push: show all notifications in the notifications area

Tags: c#, android, firebase, notifications, push

In my app, I insert the push notifications management. Now I'm testing only the Android area.

I sent the first test notifications with the FCM console. With this tool, if I send more than one notification, I see all of the in the notifications area of my phone (example: if I send 3 notifications with text "1", "2", and "3", I see all of them in the notification area).

Then, I tried to write some C# code to send these notifications from my server. I can now send the notifications from my code, but if I make the same test as above, I see only the last notification ("3") and not all of them.

I'm sure there is some parameter to be set, but I can't figure out which one is.

Do you know where have I to fix something? Below my C# code:

```
public string SendMessage()
{
    string serverKey = "myserverkey";

    try
    {
        var result = "-1";
        var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

        var regID  = "myAndroidPhoneID";


        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization:key=" + serverKey);
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"to\": \"" + regID + "\",\"data\": {\"message\": \"1This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!\",},\"priority\":10}";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return "err";
    }
}
```

I also tried to add in my json the parameter **collapse_key**, changing its value every notification, but I see always only the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using this json instead of the posted one:

```
string json = "{\"to\": \"" + regID + "\",\"notification\": {\"title\": \"New deal\",\"body\": \"20% deal!\"},\"priority\":10}";
```

Summarized all the steps here: https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/devextremephonegap-how-to-manage-push-notifications-with-fcm/